# Redirect to the encode url present in query parameter in NGINX

Tags: nginx

Nginx is not redirecting when the value of redirect URL is encoded using `encodeURIComponent`.

```
 location /redirect/ {
             return 307 $arg_target_url;
        }
```

When I enter url from the browser:

```
mylocalserver.com/redirect/?target_url=example.com%3Fx%3Dy%26z%3Dk
```

it gets redirected to

```
mylocalserver.com/redirect/example.com%3Fx%3Dy%26z%3Dk
```

The expectation is, it should be redirected to url `example.com?x=y&z=k`.

However, when `$arg_target_url` contains plain value, it does work.

Answer (score 0):

Install nginx and the njs Scripting Language, please read the installation instructions: [nginx: Linux packages](http://nginx.org/en/linux_packages.html).
Make sure to backup your configuration first.

Minimal steps to install `nginx` and the `nginx-module-njs` package from the nginx.org stable repository on Debian as example:

```
echo "deb http://nginx.org/packages/debian $(lsb_release -cs) nginx" |
  sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nginx.list

curl -fsSL https://nginx.org/keys/nginx_signing.key | sudo apt-key add -

sudo apt update
sudo apt install nginx nginx-module-njs
```

1. Add the line

   ```
   load_module modules/ngx_http_js_module.so;
   ```

   to your main configuration (`nginx.conf`).
2. Create file `http.js` in your nginx config directory with the following content:

   ```
   function decoded_target_url(r) {
       return decodeURIComponent(r.args.target_url);
   }

   export default {decoded_target_url};
   ```
3. Change your default config to this:

   ```
   js_import http.js;
   js_set $decoded_target_url http.decoded_target_url;

   server {
       # ... more stuff

       default_type text/html;

       location /redirect/ {
           return 307 $decoded_target_url;
       }

       # ... more stuff
   }
   ```
4. Run `nginx -t` to check the configuration and restart your server.

You need to add the protocol (`http://` or `https://`) to the query parameter, e.g.

```
mylocalserver.com/redirect/?target_url=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F%3Fx%3Dy%26z%3Dk
```

or change

```
return 307 $decoded_target_url
```

to a hardcoded

```
return 307 http://$decoded_target_url
```

or

```
return 307 https://$decoded_target_url
```

Related docs:

- [Module ngx_http_js_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_js_module.html)
- [URL Decoding - NJS Examples](http://nginx.org/en/docs/njs/examples.html#urldecode)